# How to Change the Blue Highlight Color around a JTextField when it gains focus in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, jtextfield

In Netbeans, whenever a JTextField, JButton, gains focus, the border gets covered by a blue highlight, how can I change its color, or remove it completely?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstraded your issue(s) with Nimbus Look and Feel, otherwise this question isn't answerable somehow ...

Comment: I'm nothing, did you read SSCCE document

Comment: Too long, looks like there's no real answer for this.

Comment: Do you mean at runtime? What L&F?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by `Changing the Theme`. Like using **Nimbus** and overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by right clicking on the component in the design view, selecting properties and then choosing the border field. From here you can choose different styles for your border using the GUI editor or edit via code using the "Change Jbutton's border property using:" selector box in the top right of the window and choosing "Custom Code".

For instance you could choose a "Bevel Border" and make the 4 parameters: "Highlight Inner Color", "Highlight Outer Color", "Shadow Inner Color" and "Shadow Outer Color" the same as the background colour to remove it completely.